# Нужно засунуть кнопку внутрь поля для ввода

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Такая проблема. Нужно засунуть кнопку внутрь поля для ввода, как это показано на рисунке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div id="search">
        <div class="container">
                <h1>....</h1>
                    <form class="has-success has-feedback has-feedback-left">
                                <label class="control-label sr-only" for="inputSearch">....</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="inputSearch" placeholder="....">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
                                <button class="btn" type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                    </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Она почему-то под низом. Как исправить? Заранее спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]